# C# any available resources for programming windows forms without VS?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am a first year student in Computer Science and we are learning Java this whole first year. I have been teaching myself Swing on the side, but I feel like it is antiquated and not very user-friendly. So I decided to start learning C#, but I cannot find any resources for learning to program Windows Form Applications programmatically, as opposed to Visual Studio. I know it might seem unnecessary, but I prefer to code everything by hand. Does anyone know of any resources that can teach WF design using code only?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: how about Notepad maybe?

Comment: Actually its not *might* seem unnecessary. It's really unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using graphical additions for visual studio anc create windows-forms-applications without it. Something like

```
class Myform :Form
{
    private Label lText;
    private Button BTN_OK;

    public Myform()
    {
        lText = new Label();
        BTN_OK = new Button();

        this.Width = 600;
        this.Height = 400;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Icon = new Icon("D:\\Icon1.ico");
        this.Text = "Stay Brutal";

        //--Button properties
        //***************************
        EventHandler eh1 = new EventHandler(OnClick);
        BTN_OK.Click += eh1;
        BTN_OK.Text = "Agree";
        BTN_OK.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        BTN_OK.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
        //***************************

        //--Label properties
        lText.Text = "Question";
        lText.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        lText.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        lText.Location = new Point(100, 200);
        lText.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
        //**************************

        this.Controls.Add(lText);
        this.Controls.Add(BTN_OK);


    }
```

Also you can write your programm in any notepad\notepad++ and use console to compile your programm.

For example : 
csc /target:winexe /out:D:\1.exe /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll
 /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll D:\
Program.txt

Answer (score 1):

There is no any restriction to work directly with the Visual Studio IDE to develop Windows Form applications - the only issue with that is the fact that it would take you *much much* longer.

To do it totally by yourself, I would suggest you to use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the required documentations about Windows Form development and to write your code with notepad (for example) and compile it with the c# complier directly.

Look at the C# compiler: [Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Comment: I realize there isn't a restriction to using it, but every tutorial I find online, even on Microsoft's site, deal with using the Visual Studio builder, but I find that a complicated unnecessary mess, and I am much better and writing code by hand than using an IDE.

Comment: Okay, in the examples, you can see which source-code files and which assembly references are come in use and easily do it manually by yourself with your own text-editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .net frame work library and can code without visiual studio.
you can code in MS Dos Prompt

by going to path like this C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0

then create file in this location and name the program file extention to program.cs and then compile like csc program.cs press enter then you need to run the program exe from the folder that just created right on the time of compilation or you can just text on dos prompt "Program" and enter

hope this will help you..